# how to take control of processes in C#

Tags: c#, applet, freeze

I need my application blocks the use like freeze or the interface of another program and then releasing it when has finished to perform operations.

I'll explain better:

from web browser the user call -> applet java call -> my program that should freeze the browser GUI or the process, then after the operations end release everything.

How can i do?

Help is much appreciated. Kind Regards

Comment: Can you post some code of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Do you mean you want to freeze the browser? that wont be good. Use MultiThreading.

Comment: yes, freeze browser generally is not good, but it serves to ensure the success of the process